# How Pagination works internally in JQ grid?

Tags: jqgrid

Is JQgrid create all records in DOM or store locally in JavaScript object show records on pagination event?
Thanks

We tried JQ grid in our project experience slowness rendering table for large number of records (10,000) with page size of 50.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid stores the local data in array and display in DOM only the portion set in rowNum parameter.

Personally I think that loading 10k records locally is to big for any grid component. This will consume a lot of memory and will slow dawn any operation in the application.

The best is to store the data on server and request only the portion you want. Look [here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/loading_data/rest_million/index.html) how we deal with 1 million records